# Code for getting multiple words in a string from user

Tags: c++, c, string

Actually i want the user to enter a *line of string having **multiple words*** in it for example "My name is ABC".
What is the C/C++ code for this purpose?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is this C/C++ language you speak of? :)

Comment: It's C beating C++ with a stick and begging for one of its pluses.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string> 
using namespace std;

int main(){

string testString;
getline(cin, testString);

{
```

if you have

```
cin >> otherVariables
```

You need to delete the newline buffer in between by adding:

```
cin.ignore()
```

You should have something like:

```
string userMessage;
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, testString);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using something like this snippet:

```
string testString;

getline(cin, testString);
```

Answer (score 2):

`#include<string>` and see `std::getline()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::getline()` to get a line from `std::cin`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
  string name;
  cout << "Enter Name: ";
  getline (cin,name);
  cout << "You entered: " << name;
}
```

Comment: you needn't escaping HTML entities in your code. Indent it by four spaces with a leading blank line, or select it and hit Ctrl·K

Comment: Wait, you didn't type std::getline. You just used getline. That means you don't have to use std:: too right.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will help you receive multiple names from user.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string name[6];
    cout << "\nEnter your name : ";
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, name[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nYou entered : " << name[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```